# linear search. Problems with my code. Basic program

Tags: c#

I have a problem with the search function under case 3. Log in for -loop is not claimed to be declared. I have tried everything possible but can not come up with the right answer. Appreciate all the help I can get!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Loggboken
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string[]> loggbok = new List<string[]>(); // Skapar vår lista som ska innehålla våra arrays 

            string[] Logg = new string[3]; //initiering av array som ska inehålla 3 element
            Logg[0] = "Titel";//initiering av 1a elementet, titel 
            Logg[1] = "inlägg"; //initiering av 2a elementet, inlägg 
            Logg[2] = DateTime.Now.ToString(); //initiering av tredje elementet, Dagens datum och tid 
            bool isRunning = true;//// Variabel för att kontrollera om programmet ska fortsätta köras
            //Metod som presenterar menyn! 

            while (isRunning)
            {
                DateTime tiden = DateTime.Now; // DateTime-metoden som skriver ut datum och tid 
                Console.WriteLine(tiden); //Utskrivning av tiden
                Console.WriteLine("\n\tVälkommen till din Loggbok!\n\t ");

                Console.WriteLine("\n\t[1] Skriv nytt inlägg i loggboken:");

                Console.WriteLine("\n\t[2] Visa sparade loggar");

                Console.WriteLine("\n\t[3] Sök inlägg");

                Console.WriteLine("\n\t[4] Avsluta programmet\n\t");

                Console.Write("\n\tVänligen gör ditt val:\t");
                int menyVal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                int nr;
                while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out nr) || nr < 1 || nr > 4) //Läser valet/siffran som användaren har gjort. Läser in om användaren har valt siffrona 1 till 4. 
                {
                    Console.Write("Försök igen, välj mellan 1-4: "); //uppmanar användaren att välja 1-4
                }
                try
                switch (menyVal)
                {
                    case 1:
                        String[] logg = new String[3];           //Skapa en ny array för varje inlägg.
                        {

                            Console.Write("\tAnge vad vill du kalla ditt inlägg: "); //sparar titeln i index 0 i vektorn "logg"
                            logg[0] = Console.ReadLine();

                            //sparar inlägget i index 1
                            Console.WriteLine("Skriv ditt inlägg:");
                            logg[1] = Console.ReadLine();
                            //sparar tiden i index 2
                            logg[2] = DateTime.Now.ToString(); //initiering av tredje elementet, Dagens datum och tid 

                            loggbok.Add(logg);//sparar inlägget i loggboken
                            Console.WriteLine("Ditt inlägg är nu sparat!");//och skriver ut att det är gjortlogBook.Add(entry[0]);


                        }
                        break;


                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("\n Nedan är dina skrivna inlägg:\n"); //Utskrift av arrayens innehåll. 
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\t-------------------\n\t"); // Gör det trevligare för användaren att läsa 

                        foreach (string[] inlägg in loggbok)
                        {

                            Console.WriteLine("\n Inlägget är skrivet: " + inlägg[2] + " \n Titel - " + inlägg[0] + " \n Inlägg - " + inlägg[1] + "\n"); //Utskrift av arrayens innehåll. 

                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.Write("Skriv in ett ord för att söka bland dina inlägg");
                        string keyword = Console.ReadLine();
                        //string[] logg = new string[3]; //dekelartion av arryaen. Behövs den ens här? 
                        for (int i = 0; i < logg.Length; i++) //For-loop för att söka igenom innehållet efter användarens innehåll. 
                        {
                            if (logg[i] == keyword)
                            {

                                Console.WriteLine("Inlägget hittades!" + logg[i] + "\n");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Inlägget hittades inte");
                            }
                        }

                        break;
                    case 4:
                        isRunning = false;
                        break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
                Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
```

Comment: something looks very wrong with the try switch declaration.  Does this code complile?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a catch after the try.

In case 3 you did not initialize the logg array:

```
case 3:
Console.Write("Skriv in ett ord för att söka bland dina inlägg");
string keyword = Console.ReadLine();

logg = new string[3]; //dekelartion av arryaen. Behövs den ens här?
```

Comment: See the code below, it went wrong in my comment above.

Comment: It is because after the logg = new string[3]; statement the logg array is empty. You should search the keyword in the loggbok list.

Answer (score 0):

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Loggboken
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{

```
        List<string[]> loggbok = new List<string[]>(); // Skapar vår lista som ska innehålla våra arrays 

        string[] Logg = new string[3]; //initiering av array som ska inehålla 3 element
        Logg[0] = "Titel";//initiering av 1a elementet, titel 
        Logg[1] = "inlägg"; //initiering av 2a elementet, inlägg 
        Logg[2] = DateTime.Now.ToString(); //initiering av tredje elementet, Dagens datum och tid 
        bool isRunning = true;//// Variabel för att kontrollera om programmet ska fortsätta köras
        //Metod som presenterar menyn! 

        while (isRunning)
        {
            DateTime tiden = DateTime.Now; // DateTime-metoden som skriver ut datum och tid 
            Console.WriteLine(tiden); //Utskrivning av tiden
            Console.WriteLine("\n\tVälkommen till din Loggbok!\n\t ");

            Console.WriteLine("\n\t[1] Skriv nytt inlägg i loggboken:");
            Console.WriteLine("\n\t[2] Visa sparade loggar");
            Console.WriteLine("\n\t[3] Sök inlägg");
            Console.WriteLine("\n\t[4] Avsluta programmet\n\t");
            Console.Write("\n\tVänligen gör ditt val:\t");
            int menyVal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            //int nr;
            //while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out nr) || nr < 1 || nr > 4) //Läser valet/siffran som användaren har gjort. Läser in om användaren har valt siffrona 1 till 4. 
            //{
                //Console.Write("Försök igen, välj mellan 1-4: "); //uppmanar användaren att välja 1-4
            //}

            switch (menyVal)
            {



                case 1:
                    String[] logg = new String[3];           //Skapa en ny array för varje inlägg.


                    {

                        Console.Write("\tAnge vad vill du kalla ditt inlägg: "); //sparar titeln i index 0 i vektorn "logg"
                        logg[0] = Console.ReadLine();

                        //sparar inlägget i index 1
                        Console.WriteLine("Skriv ditt inlägg:");
                        logg[1] = Console.ReadLine();


                        //sparar tiden i index 2
                        logg[2] = DateTime.Now.ToString(); //initiering av tredje elementet, Dagens datum och tid 


                        loggbok.Add(logg);//sparar inlägget i loggboken
                        Console.WriteLine("Ditt inlägg är nu sparat!");//och skriver ut att det är gjortlogBook.Add(entry[0]);


                    }
                    break;


                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("\n Nedan är dina skrivna inlägg:\n"); //Utskrift av arrayens innehåll. 
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\t-------------------\n\t"); // Gör det trevligare för användaren att läsa 

                    foreach (string[] inlägg in loggbok)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("\n Inlägget är skrivet: " + inlägg[2] + " \n Titel - " + inlägg[0] + " \n Inlägg - " + inlägg[1] + "\n"); //Utskrift av arrayens innehåll. 

                    }

                    break;
                case 3:

                    Console.Write("Skriv in ett ord för att söka bland dina inlägg");
                    string keyword = Console.ReadLine();

                    logg = new string[3]; //dekelartion av arryaen. Behövs den ens här? 


                    for (int i = 0; i < logg.Length; i++) //For-loop för att söka igenom innehållet efter användarens innehåll. 
                    {



                        if (logg[i] == keyword)
                        {

                            Console.WriteLine("Ordet du sökte efter finner du detta inlägg: " + logg[i]);

                        }

                        //else
                        //{

                            //Console.WriteLine("Inlägget hittades inte");
                        //}


                    }

                    break;


                case 4:
                    isRunning = false;
                    break;
            }






        }


    }
}
```

}